# Update array of objects by another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to Update array of objects by another array of objects.

I have 2 array of objects like this:

```
const array = [
  {id:'a',html:'',user:''},
  {id:'b',html:'',user:''},
  {id:'c',html:'',user:''},
];

const array_two = [
  {id:'a',html:'',user:''},
  {id:'b',html:'',user:''},
  {id:'c',html:'',user:''},
  {id:'d',html:'<p>Hello World</p>',user:'TEST USER'},
  {id:'e',html:'<p>Hello World TWO</p>',user:'TEST USER TWO'},
];
```

and I want update`enter code here` array by anotherArray

So my desired output is:

```
[
  {id:'a',html:'<p>Hello World</p>',user:'TEST USER'},
  {id:'b',html:'<p>Hello World TWO</p>',user:'TEST USER TWO'},
  {id:'c',html:'',user:''},
];
```

Comment: Sure we can help you. Please share what you have tried.

Comment: What's the logic behind this?

Comment: How is an update to `id:'d'` in `array_two` supposed to update the object with `id:'a'`?  Is there a typo in the example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (unlike your example) that you want objects with matching `id`s to update, here's how I would implement this:

1. Build an object `byId` mapping `id`s to corresponding object.
2. Loop through the updates and apply `Object.assign` to update the objects in-place, using `byId` to know which object to update.

```js
const byId = {};
array.forEach((obj) => byId[obj.id] = obj);
array_two.forEach((obj) => {
  if (!Object.hasOwnProperty(byId, obj.id)) {
    // Create new object if id doesn't already exist.
    byId[obj.id] = obj;
    array.push(obj);
  } else {
    // Update existing object.
    Object.assign(byId[obj.id], obj);
  }
});
```